# What spells cause the developer to cast black hole?

Tags: candy-box-2

So I have the purple fin, and I know casting black hole, black demons, and erase magic makes him one shot me with a black hole of his own.  Any other tips?  I can't afford the scythe yet.

Answer (score 4):

The Developer casts his black hole spell if you cast any of the following spells:

- Black Demons
- Black Hole
- Erase Magic
- Obsidian Wall

This is directly from the game's source code.

Answer (score 1):

Erase magic, or Using a black hole on him (purple fin), or Doing what I did,
I used Black Demons and he killed himself with a black hole.... :s

Comment: You get it after you get the books from the Witch lady.

Answer (score 1):

Erase Magic, Obsidian Wall, Black Demons and Black hole will cause him to do a blackhole too and instantly kill you (bear in mind, if you're close to him this will hurt him too, so if his hp is low enough he may die).

Tips:

·Spam fireball.
·Use turtle potion right before the first wave of blue squares hit. 
·Blackhole is a good idea if he has ~500k hp.
·Another way to go, which is prolly easier is to use an *unenchanted* knight's armor (so your damage doesn't get cut in half) and hit him with a scythe; his hp will go down faster and you can nuke him by casting a blackhole so he'll be hit by it twice (he hits himself too).

Answer (score 0):

black hole, obsidian wall, and erase magic then he black holes you but if you are close enough he will take damage too so if he has about 750-250 hp then you should do it. My suggestion is to buy scythe, get pain au chocolate to upgrade power, health, and spam health potions. You should also use a turtle potion to take the damage of black hole. 
:)

Answer (score -1):

The dev is one of the easiest to beat. Make sure you're strong. Around 2000hp. 
Get up to the dev. When you are at a standstill use Turtle. Then use Obsidian Wall. He instant dies. He will cast a black hole, but being a Turtle will allow you to tank the damage. Put the Merchant Hat on to get yourself 35 million candies a time.

Comment: That wasn't the question. They asked what causes the developer to cast his black hole spell, *not* how to beat him.

Answer (score -1):

- black hole
- black demons
- erase magic (logic decided to die with this one)
- obsidian wall

All of those spells activate the developer countering with black hole.

Comment: This is already covered by another answer. Please, post only if you have something new to add.