# Beating the Developer in Hard Mode

Tags: candy-box-2

I finished Candy Box 2, and then started on Hard Mode. The last thing I need to do is defeat the developer, but I'm having issues. The strategy I used in normal mode are not working for me in Hard Mode. I tried multiple Beserk potions, the BlackHole-Then-Run method, and even just brute force. He keeps killing me on the last bit of the second set of words.  **What strategy can I use here?**

I used 5 pains au chocolat (2x power, 2x magic, 1x HP) already, and have the Scythe and the enchanted spoon. I have every other piece of inventory as well. What can I do?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137143/how-do-i-kill-the-developer?rq=1

Comment: Did you try [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/137494/42984)?

Comment: @batophobia yup, and up voted the comment asking what to do in hard mode, as this method did not work for me. I tried the methods listed in that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Giant Spoon of Doom, the Octopus Crown with Jaspers, the Red gloves, and the non-enchanted Knights Armour. I cast Fireball every 5 seconds, and drank a bezerk potion once I approached him. Once my timeout was done, I drank the Turtle potion so I could last the first attack. I drank a health potion next, so I could survive beating him, just as the yellow was almost finished.

Answer (score 1):

My solution: I devoted 2 pains au chocolat to health (earning me a total of 672 HP), and the other 5 (I didn't cheat, but actually spent all the chocolate bars I could) to magic. I then brewed 2 turtle potions and a cloning potion. I wore red gloves, octopus crown with jaspers, and a scythe. I had the red shark fin, but none of the others. As soon as I entered the quest, I squeezed and cloned. Then, right before the first attack hit, I used a turtle potion. I waited until the second attack was about to hit, and cast black demons so that the developer would cast black hole. We both died at the same time, so I won.

Answer (score 0):

you could save as text, and then change the amount of power pains au chocolate used to a high number (deduct an amount of candies or lolipops if you want to be fair) and then be amazed as you have infinite power-ups!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to cheat, you can invest 4 Pain au chocolats to health, this gives you probably 2808 health.

Then you can use Scythe and try to damage him until 1/4 of his health is gone, to which you can use Black Demons, making him counter with Blackhole.